# exiting a do while loop using a string

Tags: java, loops, do-while

Okay.

Here is my question.  I am having some difficulty while making a dice game.
The part I am having issue with is making it exit using a do while loop.
Here is my code. and I'll explain what I mean further in

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dice
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
    int diceGuess;
    int rollNum, roll1, roll2, roll3;
    String playAgain = "yes";

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


     // Create two separate dice objects to create a pair of dice
            Roll die1 = new Roll();
            Roll die2 = new Roll();

    // get from the user the number of dice rolls
            System.out.print ("Please enter a number between 2 and 12 to begin: ");
            diceGuess = sc.nextInt();

    do
    {       
        // loop to show rolls
        for (rollNum = 1; rollNum <=3; rollNum++)
          {
          System.out.println("**********Roll #: " + rollNum + " ************");
            roll1 = die1.roll();
            roll2 = die2.roll();

                //if statement to display you win if you win, and to make the loop break.
                if(diceGuess==roll1+roll2)  
                    {
                        System.out.println("You win!");
                        rollNum = 4;
                    }

                if(rollNum == 3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You lose.\n");
                        System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
                        playAgain = sc.nextLine();
                        rollNum ++;
                    }
            }           
        }while(playAgain == "yes");

}
```

}

This is my utility class.
I want it to ask the user if they want to play again, and then if the user inputs no, I want it to quit.
I'm sure this is just a minor misunderstanding on my part.
Thank you very much stackoverflow.

and heres the other class

```
//Justin Le
//Dice class


import java.util.Random;

public class Roll
{
//variables used in class
private Random randomRoll = new Random();
private int roll;
boolean playAgain = false;


//constructor
public Roll()
{
    roll = 0;
}

//method named roll to return roll number and inside, calls a method to display the roll.
public int roll()
{
    roll = randomRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
    showRoll(roll);  //accesses showRoll to output in driver class.
    return roll;

}

public boolean test()
{
    playAgain = !playAgain;
    return playAgain;
}


//displays picture of dice roll
private void showRoll(int r)
    {
        switch(r)
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("One: \n" +
                                         " \n  "   +
                                         "  *  \n" +
                                         " \n  ");
            break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Two: \n" +
                                         "*    \n" +
                                         "     \n" +
                                         "    *\n");
            break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Three:\n" +
                                         "*    \n" +
                                         "  *  \n" +
                                     "    *\n");
            break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println("Four:\n" +
                                        "*   *\n" +
                                     "     \n" +
                                     "*   *\n");
            break;

            case 5:
                System.out.println("Five:\n" +
                                        "*   *\n" +
                                         "  *  \n" +
                                         "*   *\n");
            break;

            case 6:
                System.out.println("Six: \n" +
                                        "*   *\n" +
                                         "*   *\n" +
                                         "*   *\n");
            break;
            default:
                System.out.println("error\n");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You **must** use .equals() on Objects, you may use == on primitive types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your while, use `equals()` method to compare Strings.. : -

```
playAgain.equals("yes")
```

See [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for difference in comparison using `equals()` and `==`..

**In your first code: -**

```
if(rollNum == 3)
{
    System.out.println("You lose.\n");
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
    //playAgain = sc.nextLine();

    // Change your nextLine() to next()
    playAgain = sc.next();
    rollNum ++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

change

```
playAgain == "yes"
```

to

```
"yes".equals(playAgain)
```

Comment: I did that, but I think one of the issues is this..
When it gets to the point where I enter yes or no...
It just keeps giving me new lines to enter no no no no no

Answer (score 1):

use while(plyaAgain.equals("yes"));

Follow this link for details on string comparision :
[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
while(playAgain == "yes");
```

to this:

```
while(playAgain.equals("yes"));
```